# CSS - menu staying on top, current submenu active when scrolling

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

It is a bit complicated to tell when I am trying to do so I add a drawing ;) I hope it's clear enough

[image]

I want the menu to go on the top and stay here when going down, but this only after the header has been scrolled to its bottom.

[image]

I am using bootstrap and also wonder how to make the selected submenu as active when I scroll to it

```
<div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: white !important">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03" style="background-color: white">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel selected" href="#raceAbout">{{$t('race.about')}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceJourney">{{$t('race.parcours')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#racePictures">{{$t('race.photos')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceRate">{{$t('race.opinions')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceResults">{{$t('race.results')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#similarRaces">{{$t('race.similarRaces')}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div style="margin: 2em;"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `position:sticky` sounds right.

Comment: https://codepen.io/fishtoyo/pen/PqEYjY is a good example of what to do. Use the jquery to set the height of your header tag so it will change when you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting check my answer.

just add the below given css properties to nav bar:

```
position:sticky; 
top:0;
z-index:1;
```

**NOTE: check out my answer in full screen mode. Because  According to u r code navbar appears only in large screens**

Demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>

</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: white !important;position:sticky; top:0;z-index:1;">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03" style="background-color: white">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel selected" href="#raceAbout">{{$t('race.about')}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceJourney">{{$t('race.parcours')}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#racePictures">{{$t('race.photos')}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceRate">{{$t('race.opinions')}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#raceResults">{{$t('race.results')}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navbar-whitepanel" href="#similarRaces">{{$t('race.similarRaces')}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div style="margin: 2em;"></div>



<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>some contents </h1>
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .....</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>

  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>

  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>

  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
  <p style="margin-top:100px;">some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `position: sticky;` to achieve this type of navigation menu. Click on below website to read more in details.

[Open this site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)